# String variable dynamic bind

Tags: typescript

I have this code `.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})/, '($1) $2');`.

I want to pass variable to make 3 dynamic.

I tried `.replace(/^(\d{0,code.length})(\d{0,2})/, '($1) $2');`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to fill your parameters up

```js
const code = {
   length: 3
}
const regex = new RegExp(`^(\d{0,${code.length}})(\d{0,2})`)
console.log(regex)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat regexp string with your variable like this

```js
function replaceSymbols (str, symbols) {
  const regexp = new RegExp('12' + symbols, 'g')
  return str.replace(regexp, '-replace_string-')
}

const str = '123456'

console.log(replaceSymbols(str, ''));
console.log(replaceSymbols(str, '34'));
console.log(replaceSymbols(str, '345'));
```